# System chat bot should post/announce all room permission changes

Tags: feature-request, chat

I recently came across a minor issue where I added owners to a private chat room, and then started granting users explicit write access. Since the system "bot" announced all the owner additions, people kept asking me why I didn't add user X, Y, and Z to the room, when in fact I had, but with "write" access instead of owner access.

The system user should announce any explicit permissions change. But perhaps one implementation question (if possible): Should it announce them only to the relevant site mods, 10ks+, and room owners? Or to everyone as I believe is currently the case?

Comment: Related: [Granting users access to a private room should create a message in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266729/335251)